# How much size would an empty deque take?

Tags: c++, memory

How much space in memory would an empty `deque<{custom struct}*>` take?

Also if I did the following:

1. define `deque<{custom struct}*> x;`
2. `push_back` n elements
3. `pop_front` n elements
4. `deque<{custom struct}*>(x).swap(x)`

Would the final size of x be equal to an initially empty defined dequeue?

(Used `swap` referring to the following link - http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm)

Comment: Depends entirely on the standard library implementation

Comment: do you mean `sizeof( the_queue)` or the actual memory consumption? The former is a compile time constant, the latter isnt that easily to query. Perhpaps some context would help, Why do you need to know?

Comment: The latter. I'm running a long and memory-intensive program which keeps adding and deleting from several queues. I was thinking that if many of the queues are empty and take lots of size then I could replace them with null. I have millions of queues.

Comment: An empty one exactly `sizeof(std::dequeue<customstruct*>)` bytes (on the stack)

Comment: You can determine the size of a single empty queue with `sizeof()`, then estimate what chunk of memory they take at runtime. What OS are you on? Every OS has some monitoring tool, I just use `top` on Linux, run it before and during the execution of the program and look at the memory usage difference. There are GUI alternatives too, built in.